# How do I use Amazon's new RRS for S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, storage

Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) is a new service from Amazon that is a bit cheaper than S3 because there is less redundancy.

However, I can not find any information on how to specify that my data should use RRS rather than standard S3. In fact, there doesn't seem to be any website interface for an S3 services. If I log into AWS, there are only options for EC2, Elastic MapReduce, CloudFront and RDS, none of which I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [S3 Browser](http://s3browser.com) to switch to Reduced Redundancy Storage. It allows you to view/edit storage class for a single file or for multiple files. Moreover, you can configure default storage class for the bucket, so S3 Browser will automatically apply predefined storage class for all new files you are uploading through S3 Browser.

If you are using S3 Browser to work with RRS, the following article may be helpful:
[Working with Amazon S3 Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS)](http://s3browser.com/working-with-reduced-redundancy-storage-rrs.php)

Note, Storage Class preferences are stored in a local settings file.Other s3 applications are using their own way to store bucket defaults and currently there is not single standard on this.

Comment: A few of the answers refer to changing the RRS switch. Just for clarification, when you change the RRS setting the entire file is copied to a new file. You can't dynamically change the setting on existing S3 objects. S3 Browser transparently handles this, but will take a long time with large files.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is old but it's worth mentioning that Amazon's interface for S3 now has an option to change your files (recursively) to RRS. Select a folder and right click on it, under properties change the storage to RRS.

Comment: Where is this? In the Management console?

Answer (score 2):

> All objects in Amazon S3 have a
>   storage class setting. The default
>   setting is STANDARD. You can use an
>   optional header on a PUT request to
>   specify the setting
>   REDUCED_REDUNDANCY.

From: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_do_I_specify_that_I_want_to_store_my_data_using_RRS

Comment: As with most of the AWS releases, I am sure that you will get a mechanism in the AWS control panel about 6-8 months after the functional release. :-) Ylastic may have support for it now, but don't hold me to that.

Comment: I see that S3 Browser has a flag for it under properties, but I see no way to change the setting. Perhaps Cloudberry Explorer has something for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to convert existing data in amazon s3, you can use a fairly recent version of boto and a script I wrote. Details explained on my blog:

http://www.bryceboe.com/2010/07/02/amazon-s3-convert-objects-to-reduced-redundancy-storage/

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a mac, the free cyberduck ftp program will do it. Log into S3, right-click on the bucket (or folder, or file) and choose 'info' and change the storage class from 'unknown' or 'regular s3 storage' to 'reduced redundancy storage'. Took it about 2 hours to change 30,000 files for me...

Answer (score 1):

If you use boto, you can do this:

```
key.change_storage_class('REDUCED_REDUNDANCY')
```